# AngularJS+UI-Router common CRUD configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm struggling with ui-router configuration which will define basic CRUD in the  application.

I need to be able to add, remove, edit and search for, say, clients. Quite basic task.

Main page with url "/clients/" shows [Add Client] button and Keyword input field for search with [Search] button.

Once I enter something into search field and press the button I should navigate to "/clients/search/:keyword", but essentially I'll stay on the same page and search results will be loaded below the input field.

That's quite easy to implement, but interesting starts when I need to edit a client.

When I click on one of the rows from search results I expect a popup to be show with client information/form. At the same time, application should navigate to certain URL, so I can use that URL to share with someone, or basically use back button in my browser. So application should navigate to "/clients/edit/:clientId". Make total sense, right?

Similar should happen when I try to add a new client. Application navigates to "/clients/add" or "/clients/edit/0".

How would your organise routes for that? Obovioulsy, Sticky routes and Deep State Redirect are required here.
So I managed to organise it this way so far:

```
function clientStateConfig ($stateProvider, $rootScope) {

  console.log('Client State :: init');

  $stateProvider.state('main.clients', {
    url: '/clients',
    skipAuthorisation: true,
    controller: 'ClientStateController as clientState',
    template: clientStateTemplate
  }).state('main.clients.create', {
    url: '/create',
    skipAuthorisation: true,
    views: {
      'modal': {
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      }
    },
    onEnter: showClientModal
  }).state('main.clients.edit', {
    url: '/edit/:clientId',
    skipAuthorisation: true,
    views: {
      'modal': {
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
      }
    },
    onEnter: showClientModal
  }).state('main.clients.search', {
    url: '/search/:keyword',
    skipAuthorisation: true,
    deepStateRedirect: true,
    sticky: true,
    views: {
      'search': {
        template: clientSearchStateTemplate,
        controller: 'ClientSearchStateController as clientSearch'
      }
    }
  });

};

function showClientModal ($uibModal, $previousState, $rootScope) {

  $previousState.memo('modalInvoker'); // remember the previous state with memoName 'modalInvoker'

  let modal = $uibModal.open({
    template: clientModalTemplate,
    backdrop: 'static',
    controller: 'ClientModalController as clientModal'
  });

 }
```

ClientState template:

```
<h1>Clients</h1>
<div ui-view="search"></div>
<div ui-view="modal"></div>
```

Search template: 
    
    
        {{client}}

Modal and controllers code are not that relevant I think.
So the first and main problem is - when I navigate to "/clients/" I don't, obviously, see the search field, because I need to go to "/clients/search/" instead. So clients route should always redirect to search. But if it always redirects to search - here comes the problem with popups when user enters "/clients/edit/123". It shouldn't navigate in that case.

Other way: I can put search field into root ClientState template, and trigger $state.go('main.clients.search') on search button from there. Which would be ideal. But the problem will appear when user enters url "/clients/search/superkeyword" directly form the browser, and ClientState won't have access to that keyword state param as it is child state param. So keyword input field will be blank.

I completely lost and confused with. How would you solve that?

Comment: Perhaps you could use `url: '/clients?clientId'` which would add the clientId to the $stateParams and be available in your controller. You could potentially do all crud on one url with the use of $stateParams as the search could be a filter of the list, and use  `url: '/clients?clientId&keyword'`

Answer (score 0):

While you might be able to get some sort of solution working, mixing urls with modals is a pain in the ass. They usually require providing both the backing url, and modal url information in a single url (such as via query params, etc). You could do one of a few different things.

- Remove the need for modals all together. There are a couple of ways to do this.

  - You can have separate search and client pages (but that might make the UX problematic if your requirement is that users will be quickly selecting different users).
  - You can bake the search and selected client html into the same page. For example have a region that contains search results (a sidebar, or other designated area).
- Combine the search and modal urls into a single more complicated routing setup (for example `/clients/edit/:id?search=test`)
- Implement both a modal version and a single page version. The single page version will have its own url (eg. `/clients/edit/:id`), while the modal version will still function, it won't change the url of the current view.

Personally I would implement the last suggestion without modals, and then test the UX, and if the modal is definitely needed, implement it as a separate feature that won't effect urls.